# Back propagation in a multi-output neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, mathematical-optimization

I would like to write a multi output Neural Network trying to understand the mathematics of all this in accordance with https://victorzhou.com/blog/intro-to-neural-networks/

My idea:

- Array 128*128 is input (an image of a digit)
- 1 hidden layer (10 neurons)
- 1 output layer (10 neurons, first is detected digit 1, second is detected digit 2)

Trying to tune the weights and biases I get my loss is not decreasing.

Where's my mistake?

I calculate dL/dy * dy/dh * dh/dw to calculate dL/dw for the weights in the first layer when I have a picture of digit 1 (first output)

But when I get the image of the digit 2....don't...I damage my previous calculations?

How should I calculate the loss in my multioutput version?

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10JV1.png)

Here's the code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob
import random


path = 'D:\Digits'

L=128
H=10
s=0.001
k=44

imgs=[] # all my dataset images
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.png'):
            imgs.append(os.path.join(root, file))


def sig(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def deriv(x):
  fx = sig(x)
  return fx * (1 - fx)

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).mean()

class NeuralNetwork:
  def __init__(self):
      
    self.wsh=[]
    for i in range (H):
        self.wsh.append(np.random.rand(L**2))
    self.wsh=np.asarray(self.wsh)

    self.wso=[]
    for i in range (H):
        self.wso.append(np.random.rand(H))
    self.wso=np.asarray(self.wso)

    self.hs=np.random.rand(H) 
    self.bsh=np.random.rand(H) 
    self.bso=np.random.rand(H) 
    self.os=np.random.rand(H)
    self.dhdw=[]
    for i in range (H):
           self.dhdw.append(np.random.rand(L**2))
    self.dhdw=np.asarray(self.dhdw)
      
    self.dwh=[]
    for i in range (H):
           self.dwh.append(np.random.rand(L**2))
    self.dwh=np.asarray(self.dwh)

  def forward(self, x, fold):
    for i in range (H):  
        self.hs[i]=sig(np.dot(self.wsh[i],x))
    for i in range (H):
        self.os[i]=sig(np.dot(self.wso[i],self.hs))
    y_true=np.zeros(H)
    y_true[fold]=1
    print (loss(y_true,self.os))
    f = open('D:\Питон\loss.txt','a')  
    f.write(str(loss(y_true,self.os))+'\n')  
    f.close()  


  def train(self,x,j)  :
    self.dydh=np.random.rand(H)
    self.dydw=np.random.rand(H)
    self.dwo=np.random.rand(H)
      
    self.dhdb=[]
    self.dhdb=np.random.rand(H)
    
    self.dydb=[]
    self.dydb=np.random.rand(H)

    self.dbh=[]
    self.dbh=np.random.rand(H)


    dL = -2*(1-self.os[j])
    for k in range (H):
        self.dydh [k]= self.wso[j][k] * deriv(np.dot(self.wso[k],self.hs))
    #print ('dydh done')    
    for t in range (H):
        t1=deriv(np.dot(self.wsh[t],x))
        for g in range (L**2):
           self.dhdw [t][g]= x[g]* t1 #deriv(np.dot(self.wsh[t],x))
        #print ('dhdw - ',t)              
    #print ('dhdw done')           
    for t in range (H):
        t2=s * dL * self.dydh [t]
        for g in range (L**2):
            self.dwh[t][g] = t2 * self.dhdw [t][g]
            self.wsh[t][g] -= self.dwh[t][g]
    #print ('wsh done')            
    for t in range (H):
        self.dydw[t] = self.hs[t] * deriv (np.dot(self.hs,self.wso[t]))
    #print ('dydw done')        

    for t in range (H):
        self.dwo[t] = s * dL * self.dydw [t]
        self.wso[j][t] -= self.dwo[t]
    #print ('wso done')

    
    for t in range (H):
        self.dhdb[t] = deriv (np.dot(self.wsh[t],x))
        self.bsh[t] = self.bsh[t] - s * dL * self.dydh[t] * self.dhdb[t]
    
    for t in range (H):
        self.dydb[t] = deriv (np.dot(self.wso[t],self.hs))
        self.bso[t] = self.bso[t] - s * dL * self.dydb[t] 
            
    
N=NeuralNetwork()

#read the weights from the past
N.wsh = np.loadtxt("D:\Питон\\wsh"+str(k-1)+".npy")
N.wso = np.loadtxt("D:\Питон\\wso"+str(k-1)+".npy")
N.bsh = np.loadtxt("D:\Питон\\bsh"+str(k-1)+".npy")
N.bso = np.loadtxt("D:\Питон\\bso"+str(k-1)+".npy")


for i in range (100):
   
    file=imgs[random.randint(0,len(imgs))]
    fold=int(file[10])

    img =Image.open(file) 
    img=np.asarray(img)
    img = [element for row in img for element in row]


    #print(str(k),"-ая эпоха")
    N.forward(img,fold)
    
    N.train(img,fold)
    np.savetxt("D:\Питон\\wsh"+str(k)+".npy",N.wsh)
    np.savetxt("D:\Питон\\wso"+str(k)+".npy",N.wso)
    np.savetxt("D:\Питон\\bsh"+str(k)+".npy",N.bsh)
    np.savetxt("D:\Питон\\bso"+str(k)+".npy",N.bso)
    
    k+=1    
type here
```

I am getting weird results

Comment: Aleksey, looks like you have made a good start on the problem. Here's some advice which is applicable to debugging any complex function. Start with a smaller version of the problem; how about recognizing "0" versus all other digits. That allows you to have one output unit. Try using fewer hidden units, maybe zero (i.e., then your model is identical to logistic regression). Try using a smaller input, say 8 by 8 to start with. To check the gradient calculation, compute the gradient by finite differences and compare that to your computed gradient.

Comment: If you get the small problem working, then add complexity back in one step at a time.